# React PropType validation is not working since Webpack 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, react-proptypes

We are using the following npm packages (along with many other):

```
"dependencies": {
  "prop-types": "15.5.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "autodll-webpack-plugin": "0.4.2",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.5.3",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
  "react": "16.4.2",
  "stats-webpack-plugin": "0.7.0",
  "webpack": "4.20.2",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.0.2",
  "webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.9",
  "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11"
}
```

Here I just list all the **Webpack** related packages along with the *version* or **React** and **PropTypes** we are using. Obviously much more packages are used (which might cause the problem).

> The problem is that since we updated **Webpack** from version 3 to 4, the **PropTypes** validation does not work.

Maybe the problem is not Webpack related but since the upgrade **we do not receive *console error* in development mode** if we omit an `isRequired` property.

The website runs flawlessly with `webpack-dev-server`.
We initiate the server using the following command:
`webpack-dev-server --mode=development`

In the code if I output the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` to the console of the browser, I get `development`. Yet if I omit an `isRequired` property, the application does not warn in the console output of the browser as it *did before* **using Webpack 3**.

`defaultProps` is not used for the `isRequired` property.

Thank you for your help, and please let me know if you need more information for the investigation!

Comment: Hello :), I've had a similar issue quite recently with the webpack and propTypes versioning. Could you please give me more details about the error itself, like a screenshot of what the browser network shows ? Maybe I could be of assistance. Thanks!